# How to extend a subscription after a customer submits payment

Tags: stripe-payments

When I direct a user with an existing subscription to the Stripe payment page, Stripe automatically creates a new subscription at the time the customer submits payment.

What is the workflow that will allow me to tell Stripe that I want to extend the existing subscription and not create a new one?

I asked this question to Stripe support and this is the answer I got:

> To answer your question, this will depend on your integration if you are using a third party platform to create this option, but with Stripe, this can only be done manually using the reference that we provided, this means that you have to extend the subscription without requiring a customer to make a payment first.

With regard to the third party platform, I don't understand why the API works differently for them and for me.  Does this mean Stripe has a secret API and I MUST purchase a third party product to use the service effectively?

> this means that you have to extend the subscription without requiring a customer to make a payment first.

This is the part that is giving me grief.  This seems like an extraordinarily difficult workflow.  At what point do I extend the subscription?  What if the customer never pays?  What triggers me to un-extend it?  How can I reliably report to the customer the date their subscription ends?  Extending a subscription seems like a fundamental, mundane task.  Can it really be this difficult?

Edit code posted per requests:

```
SessionCreateOptions options = new SessionCreateOptions
{
    PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> { "card" },
    LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
    {
        new SessionLineItemOptions { Price = order.PaymentProviderPlanID, Quantity = 1 }
    },
    Customer = order.CustomerID,
    CustomerEmail = string.IsNullOrEmpty(order.CustomerID)? order.UserEmail : null,
    Mode = "subscription",
    SuccessUrl = hostURL + "/Subscription/CreateSubscription?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",    
    CancelUrl = hostURL + "/SubActivationFailure",                                                  
};
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "extend the subscription"? Is it set to cancel at some date, or has it already been cancelled?

Comment: @NolanH By extend I mean to renew.  Yes it will be set to cancel at the end of the subscription period if the customer does not renew.  I suppose it could be expired or cancelled. Most likely it will still be active but nearing it's expiration date.

Comment: I suspect there is more information needed to understand the workflow here, which you may have left out not realizing it is important. Unless you specify otherwise, subscriptions will continue indefinitely. If you've set a subscription to cancel at period end, for example, you can undo that by sending `cancel_at_period_end=false` to the subscription update endpoint. https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/cancel#reactivating-canceled-subscriptions

Comment: There is no need for you to use a 3rd party service to accomplish this, but it would help if you shared the details of how you're creating these subscriptions and setting them to cancel.

Comment: I don't create the subscription manually. Stripe does that when customer pays and I don't touch it.  I can look in the portal and see the current period end date is set correctly based on the billing cycle of the pricing item.  See updated question for code.

Comment: So you're creating subscriptions using Checkout, which is a great choice.  By default, these subscriptions will renew and automatically invoice your customer each month, unless you've explicitly set something different to happen. Perhaps this is just a misunderstanding of the expected default behaviour? Once the subscription is started successfully, you don't need to do anything to collect payment for future months, unless there are payment failures: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#payment-failures

Comment: OK this is good, so perhaps what I am asking for is how do I generate a link that says "Go here to pay your invoice"?  Very sorry that my approach to this is a little different.  In my code I have reached a place where I am asking "What do I do if a customer with an existing sub tries to create a new one?".  My thought process is to just direct them to the Checkout screen and tell Checkout to extend their existing sub.  However if the workflow is to send them to a different page to pay an invoice I'm good with that too.
I need to account for situations where cust looses invoice from Stripe.

Comment: Unless you've set the subscriptions to use `collection_method=send_invoice` explicitly, the default is `charge_automatically`. This, as the name suggests, will charge your customer automatically each month. By default, they don't need to do anything and neither do you.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-collection_method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per clarifications to the question in the comments, do nothing and this will happen automatically. This is the default unless you explicitly set a subscription to cancel or for invoice to not be paid automatically.